# glitches in texture in blender texture drowing

Tags: texturing

When I paint a texture in blender I have glitches on it.
It looks like this:

[image]

[image]

I think, it is because i hadn`t graphics card in my pc. If i think incorect, please, tell me how can i fix this issue.

Comment: Will the final model be one color or multiple colors?  If multiple colors please show mulitple colors because one color is a simpler case.

Comment: Please be specific about the goal you want and what failed. Glitch is vague. Even so I will attempt to guess at what failed. Are the small unpainted holes the failure? This has zero to do with the gpu graphics card.

Comment: Model will be multiple colors. On this model it isn`t so noticeable but in enother causes it spoils all work. Glitches primary appear on the seams, but when i use fill brush they appear inside the UV islands. I tryed to change UV mapping, but it wos useless.

Comment: I tryed different versions of blender. Also i chenged my os from Linux (ubuntu 18.04) to windows 10. But all this actions was useless so i think that there is problem in my gpu. Also i tired painting texturs in blender internal and result didn`t change.

Answer (score 1):

Painting

- If the model is only one color directly you can assign the material.
- You can paint the model directly with different colors.  You may need to twist and turn the model so the faces of  little nooks and crannies (small tight spaces) are directly facing you the painter.  You can hide parts of the 3D Mesh so that the tight spaces are more obviously accessible.
- You may paint on the texture directly to fill in the holes.  Enter paint mode for the texture and paint directly to fill in holes.